# How should I design nested url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

For now, I'm setting up my nested routing like this
But in this case,

- **example.com/shop/walmart/topic/1**  <= if I create a topic first time
- **example.com/shop/bestbuy/topic/2**  <= if I create a topic second time
- **example.com/shop/walmart/topic/3**  <= if I create a topic third time

In spite of the fact there are only 2 records that belong to **walmart shop**
The ID will be shown as **'3'**
How can I make this ID as count up style? Should I prepare another column or something?

> ```
> resources :communities, :path => "shop", do
> resources :community_topics, :path => "topic", :as => :'topic'
> end
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it *really* matter if the number in the url is the `id` of the record?  If that matters to you, you can make a number 'slug' similar to your shop slug "walmart", "bestbuy" etc.  You'll have to make a new column in the topics table and use a `before_create` filter to increment that value.  Something like this:

```
class Topic
  before_validation :increment_slug, :on :create
  validates_uniqueness_of :slug, scope: :shop_id

  private
  def increment_slug
    self.slug = Topic.where("shop_id = ?", shop_id).order("slug DESC").limit(1).slug + 1
  end
end
```

Make sure 'slug' here is a numeric field so the `+` and sorting work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I wanna ask you which way is more common way to do??? Developer usually don't care and never do this special transcation?

Comment: Not usually.  We have some nested routes in our apps but we just let that `id` be in the route.  A customer will never care that `/bestbuy/topics/4` has a page but `/bestbuy/topics/5` is a 404 even though there's a `/bestbuy/topics/6`.  I would just go with the default rails convention of using an `id` there personally, unless there's some very specific business reason you'd want alternate behavior.

Comment: Thank you for explanation with good example of your app. Thanks again!! I appreciate!!